# Docker task in Azure devops won't accept "$(pwd)' as variable

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I tried to run a docker command through the docker task in Azure devops with the build in docker task.
As variable for the volume of the docker command I gave this as value
[image]

But it keeps failing with the error

```
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd)/out: "$(pwd)/out" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
```

I tried to give the same docker run command with the same -v value inside my local machine and this works perfectly. So I guess this is an Azure devops problem or a value that I forget to give along

My host agent is an ubuntu16
And the build task is as followed
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to reference a variable named `pwd`.  There is [no such predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts) in Azure Pipelines.

You mention that this works in your local machine, but that's not because there's a `pwd` variable defined.  (In fact, there's probably *not* a `pwd` environment variable in your environment.)  That's because `$(pwd)` is [POSIX command substitution](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).  It's actually *executing* the `pwd` command.

This POSIX shell syntax will not work in Azure Pipelines configuration.

Instead, use one of the [Azure Pipelines variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=vsts).

For example, if you want to map the sources directory, you can set the volumes field to:

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory):/src
```

Or map source and binaries:

```
 $(Build.SourcesDirectory):/src
 $(Build.BinariesDirectory):/build
```