# Mount repo into docker image when running yaml-pipeline in Azure DevOps

Tags: docker, azure-devops, mounted-volumes

I am running a docker image in Azure Devops yaml-pipeline using a [container step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#options). However, I have problems mounting the content of the repo so that this is accessible from inside the docker image.

The Azure Devops pipeline.yml file is as follows:

```
container:
  image: 'image-name'
  endpoint: 'foo'
  options: '-v $(Build.SourcesDirectory):/testing'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script inside docker image'
```

This fails with the error message:

```
Error response from daemon: create $(Build.SourcesDirectory): "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)" includes 
invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended 
to pass a host directory, use absolute path
```

I also tried replacing `$(..)$` with `$[..]` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#runtime-expression-syntax) but this results in the same error. Also with `${{..}}` the pipeline will not even start (error: "A template expression is not allowed in this context" in the UI)

If I remove `options` the script runs, but the repo is not mounted.

For non-yaml pipelines, the question was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143789).

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Or do I need to create a new docker image where the repo files have been add:ed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Any ideas how to accomplish this? Or do I need to create a new docker
>   image where the repo files have been add:ed?

When specifying the `Container` using Yaml Schema directly, the Azure DevOps Service will call an extra `Initialize containers` task automatically before `checkout source repo` task and your real tasks.

```
container:
  image: 'image-name'

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script inside docker image'
```

[image]

During the `Initialize containers` task, the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) like `Agent.BuildDirectory`, `Build.Repository.LocalPath` and `Build.SourcesDirectory` are not expanded (non-defined variables).

So you can't use the `Build.SourcesDirectory` in this way cause the value of this variable is expanded **after** the `Initialize containers` task.

1.About why [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143789/docker-task-in-azure-devops-wont-accept-pwd-as-variable) you shared above can work: It's in a [docker task/step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops) so it can recognize the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` variable. (The real build tasks run **after** the build variables are defined)

2.If you're using specific [Micorosft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), you can try hard-coding the path. You can check this [similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/7528).

Usually for windows-hosted agent: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`=> `D:\a\1\s`

For Ubuntu-hosted agent: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`=> `/home/vsts/work/1/s`.

Comment: Really good answer, elaborating on all the pieces, the expansion timing and the different options and the ones which seem so, but are not - and the 'why'. Thank you!