# AzureDevops Buildpipeline can not recognise docker volume mount

Tags: docker, azure-devops

In my build pipeline, I'm trying to run the below task:
The main responsibility of the task is to mount the volume for `Test` and the `Script` from the AzDo to the container's working dir which is `/app/` and then run the `test`(basically it will run npm test inside the container). But unfortunately, I don't see any outcomes. Hence I changed the command as `ls -ltrR /app` at the end of the docker run to check if the files are copied or not. But I see the directory is created but no files are inside.

So, to prove the files exist in `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` for AzDo. I tried to run all kinds of `ls commands` prior to docker-run which shows that the files do exist in the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory). But for some reason files are not mapped in docker containers. I tried to use `PWD` and `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` but in all cases, it is not working.

I tried to replicate the same docker run command using in my local workstation, it works as expected. So, can anyone suggest how to mount the files in the docker run using AzDo build task?

```
- task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          echo "check in if Scripts and Tests file exists"
          ls -Rtlr ./Script
          cat ./Script/dev_blueprint_jest2/MyJavaScript.js
          ls -ltrR $PWD/Script
          ls -ltr $PWD/Test
          ls -ltrR $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Script/
          docker run -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Script/:/app/ScriptStages/ -v $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Test/:/app/Test/ -i dockerimage ls -ltrR /app/
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      displayName: 'Run the JS test pipeline.
```

Comment: If possible, please check this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025650/mount-repo-into-docker-image-when-running-yaml-pipeline-in-azure-devops

Comment: @joy I'm not using container steps however In my case i'm using Linux based agent, so I tried to hardcode the path `/home/vsts/work/1/s`  in my bind mount volume. But still does not work.